# Struct Members initialization

Tags: c++

How do I initialize the member variables in the following code?

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    typedef struct Employee{
        char firstName[56];
        char lastName[56];
    };

    typedef struct Company {
        int id;
        char title[256];
        char summary[2048];
        int numberOfEmployees;
        Employee *employees;
    };

    typedef struct Companies{
        Company *arr;
        int numberOfCompanies;
    };
}
```

Comment: if it is not c structs, you can add a constructor

Comment: Use a ctor and get rid of the `typedef`s--they're not doing you any good. Defining a `struct` inside of `main` is pretty unusual too. Oh, and you usually want `std:string` instead of` `char foo[xxx];`.

Comment: This is part of a bigger project(where i have it in a class).Also i will change char  to string.

Comment: here is a little something to get you started http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a027800506229467

Answer (score 1):

You can add a constructor like this one:

```
struct Employee{
        char firstName[56];
        char lastName[56];

        Employee() //name the function as the struct name, no return value.
        {
           firstName[0] = '\0';
           lastName[0] = '\0';
        }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

first: u use typedef in a wrong way

```
typedef struct Employee{
    char firstName[56];
    char lastName[56];
};
```

you need the other name for typedef

```
typedef struct _Employee{
        char firstName[56];
        char lastName[56];
    }Employee;
```

but since u're using c++ typedef is not needed.

Second: don't declare structs inside the function. Declare them **outside** of main.

Third: use **constructors** to initialize members to default value, example:

```
struct Employee{
   Employee()
   {
       strcpy (firstName, ""); //empty string
       strcpy (lastName, "asdasd"); // some value, every object now by default has this value
   }
        char firstName[56];
        char lastName[56];
    };
```

fourth: use std::string class (#include) for easier string handling

fifth: consider to type class instead struct, the only difference between those two, is that class declares the variables as private by default(you can change visibility of variable urself), while struct declares them as public by default.

Answer (score 0):

As you are already use `std::string` as indicated from the `#include` statement, you should change your classes declarations as follows (and do so outside of `main()` functions body):

```
struct Employee {
    std::string firstName;
    std::string lastName;
};
typedef struct Company {
    int id;
    std::string title;
    std::string summary;
    int numberOfEmployees;
    Employee *employees;
};
typedef struct Companies{
    Company *arr;
    int numberOfCompanies;
};
```

Comment: As i said before i will change it.Also it is a part of a bigger project where i don't have it in main.For now, all i want is to help me initialize thse variables.